# Como resolver o erro ORA-01795 (número máximo de expressões) no Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, oracle, pl-sql, where

Estou desenvolvendo um relatório no Codeigniter, porém o meu select contém um filtro que pode ter mais de 1000 expressões no meu `where_in` e então ele me retorna o erro:

```
ORA-01795: o número máximo de expressões em uma lista é de 1000.
```

Estou fazendo meu where assim:

```
$this->db->where_in("R.CODIGO",$this->db->escape($filters['CODIGO']));
```

Onde a variável `$filters['CODIGO']` é um array com 1000 elementos ou mais.

Como resolver isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu usuário tem tantos registros assim? Se for o caso o `in` não é perfornatico para tal cenario, alias, ele nem ao menos funciona. Para este numero de registro aconselho o uso de um `EXISTS`

O `exists` trabalha com um subquery, abaixo um exemplo de sintax:

```
SELECT *
FROM customers
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM order_details
              WHERE customers.customer_id = order_details.customer_id);
```

Caso não funcione você pode fazer uma adaptação e concatenar os `in` em varios `or` limitando a mil cada, lembrando que ficará lento e não é o correto, algo próximo a isso:

```
where
shogen_no in ('one', 'two', 'three') or
shogen_no in ('four', 'five', 'six') or ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Segue abaixo uma forma para contornar a situação do erro ORA-01795.

Basicamente em destaque **negrito** você terá seu comando principal.
Em *itálico* você precisará quebrar toda sua relação de cpfs/cnpjs de 1000 em 1000 unidos pelo termo *UNION*. Pode usar quantas vezes achar necessário para uma terceira listagem por exemplo.

SQL:

**SELECT COUNT(Z.CNPJ)
FROM
(**
*SELECT CNPJ FROM PESSOAS WHERE CNPJ IN ('123.456.789-10', '...' , 'milésimo cnpj da listagem')
UNION
SELECT CNPJ FROM PESSOAS WHERE CNPJ IN ('111.222.333-44', '...' , 'milésimo cnpj da segunda listagem')*
**) Z**

Result: 2000 cnpjs

Ou seja, desta forma você tem uma variável Z.CNPJ que poderá relacionar com suas informações do SQL como bem entender.

Exemplo, uma possível relação de faturamento por pessoa.

SELECT Z.CNPJ, FAT.DATA, FAT.VALOR
FROM FATURAMENTO FAT A INNER JOIN
(
SELECT ID_PESSOA, CNPJ
FROM PESSOAS WHERE CNPJ IN ('123.456.789-10')
UNION
SELECT ID_PESSOA, CNPJ
FROM PESSOAS WHERE CNPJ IN ('111.222.333-44')
) Z ON A.EMPRESA = Z.ID_PESSOA

Espero ter contribuído.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).