# Consulta SQL - ORA-01795

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

Estou precisando fazer um relatório a partir de uma consulta ao banco de dados. O problema é que a consulta retorna mais de 1000 expressões e apresenta o seguinte erro:

> ORA-01795: o número máximo de expressões em uma lista é de 1000.

Segue a query:

```
        string idsAcoes = string.Join(",\n", listaAcoes.Select(a => a.IdAcao));

        var sql = "SELECT l.LOGM_CD_USUA_OPERACAO, "
                + "  l.LOGM_IN_OPERACAO, "
                + "  l.LOGM_DT_OPERACAO, "
                + "  l.LOGM_TX_DADO_INICIAL, "
                + "  l.LOGM_TX_DADO_FINAL "
                + "FROM LOG_GESTAO_MUDANCA l, ACAO_MUDANCA am "
                + "WHERE l.LOGM_DS_OPERACAO = 'AcaoMudanca' "
                + "  AND l.LOGM_TX_DADO_FINAL LIKE '<AcaoMudanca>%<Id>'||am.ACMU_SQ_ACAO_MDNC||'</Id>%<DataPrazo>%' "
                + "  AND am.ACMU_SQ_ACAO_MDNC IN (" + idsAcoes + ") ";

        resultado = _session
             .CreateSQLQuery(sql)
             .List<dynamic>();
```

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/249313/como-resolver-o-erro-ora-01795-n%C3%BAmero-m%C3%A1ximo-de-express%C3%B5es-no-codeigniter

Comment: Melhor cenário seria uma subquery no lugar do IN trazendo os IDs da tabela de origem dele. A 'listaAcoes' traz os IDs de onde? É um select no BD mesmo?

Comment: Eu recebo como parâmetro no método, mas a lista vem de uma consulta no BD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Crie uma tabela temporária para conter os IDs desejados;
2. Modifique sua *query* para referenciar a tabela temporária.

Exemplo:

```
CREATE PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE ora$ptt_t_IDS (
    ID         NUMBER
);
```

Declaração WHERE modificada:

```
[...] AND am.ACMU_SQ_ACAO_MDNC IN (SELECT ID FROM ora$ptt_t_IDS);
```

<sup>Referência:

*Private Temporary Tables in Oracle Database 18c*

https://oracle-base.com/articles/18c/private-temporary-tables-18c</sup>

Comment: Existe alguma outra solução em que não seja necessário criar essa tabela temporária? Pois imagino que teria que criar em todos os ambientes (teste, desenvolvimento, homologação e produção)

Comment: @GabrielGC talvez se seu código for modificado para consultar diretamente as fontes relevantes do conteúdo que, no lado C#, sofrem `string.join()`; a limitação de 1000 parâmetros, porém, é real e não modificável. Outra possibilidade é a geração da lista via `UNION` (`IN (1..1000) UNION (1001..2000) UNION [...]`), mas esta solução é tão subpar que só menciono como exercício mental.

Answer (score 1):

Se você criar um parâmetro do tipo `CLOB` e atribuir sua lista como sendo o valor deste parâmetro, você pode dividir esta lista em tempo de execução, através de uns truques com `CONNECT BY` e não haverá a necessidade de criar uma tabela temporária...

Exemplo:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(RPAD(lst.nro, INSTR(lst.nro || ',', ',') - 1)) valor
  FROM (SELECT SUBSTR(:p_acoes, INSTR(',' || :p_acoes, ',', 1, ROWNUM)) nro
          FROM dual
       CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= LENGTH(:p_acoes) - NVL(LENGTH(REPLACE(:p_acoes, ',')), 0) + 1) lst
```

Depois você colocar no seu `IN` essa query...

```
SELECT l.logm_cd_usua_operacao,
       l.logm_in_operacao,
       l.logm_dt_operacao,
       l.logm_tx_dado_inicial,
       l.logm_tx_dado_final
  FROM log_gestao_mudanca l, acao_mudanca am
 WHERE l.logm_ds_operacao = 'AcaoMudanca'
   AND l.logm_tx_dado_final LIKE
       '<AcaoMudanca>%<Id>' || am.acmu_sq_acao_mdnc || '</Id>%<DataPrazo>%'
   AND am.acmu_sq_acao_mdnc IN (SELECT TO_NUMBER(RPAD(lst.nro, INSTR(lst.nro || ',', ',') - 1)) valor
                                  FROM (SELECT SUBSTR(:p_acoes, INSTR(',' || :p_acoes, ',', 1, ROWNUM)) nro
                                          FROM dual
                                       CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= LENGTH(:p_acoes) - NVL(LENGTH(REPLACE(:p_acoes, ',')), 0) + 1) lst)
```

Comment: Vou testar essa solução e dou o retorno..

Comment: Pesquisando sobre, eu percebi que o mais indicado nessa situação é criar uma tabela temporária. Em questão de performance sabe me falar se tem um diferença significativa?

Comment: Depende de como você vai popular essa tabela temporária... Teria que testar. Além do mais, com tabela temporária você irá precisar ter uma transação. O que não é realmente necessário, já que você está fazendo apenas uma consulta. Pensando um pouco em segurança, esse exemplo poderia ser executada por um usuário que tem somente acesso à leitura.

Comment: @BrunoWarmling Existem 2 problemas - não com sua abordagem, mas com a implementação dos drivers para .NET (System.Data.OracleClient e Oracle.DataAccess). Payloads grandes geram ORA-06550/PLS-00172. O primeiro é o limite do parser (4kb) em queries, ou o limite em stored procedures (32kb). Referência: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557995/issues-calling-stored-procedure-from-c-sharp-with-large-clob

Comment: @OnoSendai Sim, mas esses são problemas da implementação em c# e não da query. O erro `ORA-06550/PLS-00172` só ocorre se você passar um maior que 4kb para um parâmetro do tipo `varchar`. Neste caso o parâmetro no c# deve ser definido como `CLOB`, assim como mencionado na resposta. E outra, que não é uma boa pratica concatenar "valores" de parâmetros no meio da query e sim fazer isso através de bindings.

Comment: @BrunoWarmling exato - e o autor da pergunta especificou a tag C# em sua pergunta, por isso o comentário.

Answer (score -2):

Engane o Oracle.

Você pode pegar de mil em mil e juntar os vários INs com ORs, já que o Oracle não deixa pegar mais de mil,

```
const int qtde = 1000;

var sql = "SELECT l.LOGM_CD_USUA_OPERACAO, "
        + "  l.LOGM_IN_OPERACAO, "
        + "  l.LOGM_DT_OPERACAO, "
        + "  l.LOGM_TX_DADO_INICIAL, "
        + "  l.LOGM_TX_DADO_FINAL "
        + "FROM LOG_GESTAO_MUDANCA l, ACAO_MUDANCA am "
        + "WHERE l.LOGM_DS_OPERACAO = 'AcaoMudanca' "
        + "  AND l.LOGM_TX_DADO_FINAL LIKE '<AcaoMudanca>%<Id>'||am.ACMU_SQ_ACAO_MDNC||'</Id>%<DataPrazo>%' "
        + "  AND ( ";

string or = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < listaAcoes.Count; i += qtde)
{
    var milItens = listaAcoes.Select(s => s.IdAcao).Skip(i).Take(qtde);
    string separadosPorVirgula = string.Join(',', milItens);
    sql += or + "am.ACMU_SQ_ACAO_MDNC IN (" + separadosPorVirgula + ")";
    or = " OR ";
}

sql += " )";

resultado = _session
     .CreateSQLQuery(sql)
     .List<dynamic>();
```